# HighCharts - HightStock inverted axes with scroll navigator

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I'm trying the **Highcharts** tools to display some graph with huge amount of data and series comparison.

the king of graph I need is exactly the one given in [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare).

Except that mine has to be displayed in vertical ( with the time line on y axis, from the top to the bottom, and value on the x axis)

like the 'spline inverted' example ( [seen here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-inverted) ) show,  it's quite useful to display altitude related data for example.

I can easily imagine to invert values and exchange axis legends, but I don't think the time line navigator will follow...

I also tried to set the graph as inverted like in the 'Spline with inverted axes' example :

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
           chart: {
               renderTo: 'container',
               inverted: true
           },
...
```

but it didn't work.

Is there a way to display the exact same graph in vertical  with the time line navigator on the y axis ?

EDIT : its seems its not possible to use invert on HighStock graphs ([as seen in doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart)), 
So I adjust my question : 
Can we use an HighCharts inverted graph to display as many points that in HighStock charts ? (even if we won't get any scroll navigator on the y-axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highstock doesn't support inverted charts, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart

EDIT:
It is possible to use inverted Highcharts with dataGrouping, it of course requires Highstock in files, but just create chart using Highcharts.Chart(). Don't forget to enable dataGrouping from Highstock. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/PATyv/2/

Code:

```
 window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            inverted: true
        },
        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
        },
        tooltip: {
            style: {
                width: '200px'
            },
            valueDecimals: 4
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data,
            id: 'dataseries',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }]
    });
```

Comment: ok thank you for your answer. I'm still looking for a solution for inverted graph with many points. I've edited my question in that way.

Comment: also, I'd like to know. Do you think inverted highstock charts with y-axis navigator will be implemented in the future ?

Comment: Updated answer, you can vote/create an idea [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general) to implement extra features in Highstock.

Comment: seen your example on jsfiddle,  it seems to fit my needs. I'll do more investigation on it. Thank you.

Comment: Just a follow-up. We started works on scrollbar, which will work for both, inverted and non-inverted charts. Please, take a look [here](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2364547-add-navigation-bar-for-y-axis-in-highstock). It's not working for a navigator, only scrollbar, but you may be interested in this :)

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore. We ended up using this datagrouping solution on inverted chart and developped our own navigation scroll bar with an editable range.  Thank you anyway.